# node bash permission denied

Tags: javascript, node.js

I write a nodejs bash hello.js

```
#! /usr/local/bin node
console.log('Hello');
```

and

```
$ sudo chmod +x hello.js
$ ./hello.js
```

however, bash return

```
zsh: permission denied: ./hello.js
```

Comment: FWIW, `zsh` is not `bash`. Both are shells, but they're *different* shells.

Comment: Glad the answer helped. I think this is just a "typo" question, so please feel free to delete it (you have a "delete" link on the question which you're allowed to use if there are no upvoted answers) rather than accepting my answer. Best,

Comment: Moving my previous answer into a comment so you can delete the question: *"Your hashbang is incorrect, it should be: `#! /usr/local/bin/node`"*

Answer (score 1):

This is a Node/JavaScript script, not a Bash script.
In the script just write:

```
console.log('Hello');
```

Then execute it with `node ./hello.js`.
You must have NodeJS installed.